# PostgreSQL JDBC FLOAT8 transmitted as String

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

While profiling loading of large dataset from Postgres 9.3.5 with latest JDBC drivers (9.4-1201-jdbc41), I noticed that lots of time is spent inside AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.getDouble() method, where the driver is converting a String value to double using Double.toDouble().

Looking at the source code, seems like there is a way to transmit double values in binary format, but I could not find any way to force server to send back binary encoded double values (tried setting binaryTransfer to true in the connection string as suggested in https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/JDBC-BinaryTransfer, did not change anything).

Did anybody encounter similar behaviour while loading data from Postgres, or has any insight on why is this implemented this way? I found recent discussion of similar question in here  http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/36333.1430411802@sss.pgh.pa.us#36333.1430411802@sss.pgh.pa.us), but there were no conclusive answers provided there.

Comment: That wiki page appreads to be referring to a patch for the stock JDBC driver. The [documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html) mentions a `binaryTransferEnable` option, which takes a list of datatypes.

Comment: Also, looking at the [simple query protocol](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/protocol-flow.html#AEN102836), I can't see an opportunity for the client to specify the format. This might only be possible under the extended protocol (`protocolVersion=3` in JDBC, but this should be the default).

Comment: Binary transfers aren't the default for robustness and compatibility reasons, but it's actually also slower and uses more bandwidth for common cases like small integer types.

Comment: Debugging through AbstractJdbc2Connection shows that FLOAT8 (OID: 701) is added by default in the constructor, so I don't think there is a need to specify it in binaryTransferEnable option.

Comment: Not being an expert in this, I would think there should be some binary standard at least for x86 platform that one should be able to enable on the Postgres server side to improve performance (I understand it's Java/JDBC, but the driver already has the code to support it).

Comment: @Craig Ringer: how did you measure it, I would be curious to witness it too.

Comment: @Altair7852 No, it is driver side. The driver must ask PostgreSQL to send binary results if it wants them. This is already supported by PgJDBC.

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute the statement at least 5-6 (or maybe more) to get binaryTransfer mode. More at: https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/642